# Can I use the Windows 8 mail app with Exchange without adding a Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows-8, email, windows-store-app, microsoft-account

I am using Windows 8 at work. Our Exchange server is configured to allow access from the Windows 8 mail app. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to use the mail app without first adding a [Microsoft Account](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-live/sign-in-what-is-microsoft-account). Is it possible to utilize the Windows 8 mail app with a corporate Exchange server without first associating a Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 1):

would this answer help? Its a question regarding mail in Windows 8 and linking it to Exchange. [How to connect Windows 8 Mail, Calendar and People to Exchange Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/464314/how-to-connect-windows-8-mail-calendar-and-people-to-exchange-server)

Comment: Unfortunately this question focuses on **after** you have already added a Microsoft Account. To better explain if I add the Microsoft Account I'll be able to add the Exchange account without issue. I want to skip adding the Microsoft Account and just add the Exchange account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. AFAIK, using communication <strike>Metro</strike> Windows Store apps (like Mail, Calendar, People, Messaging) in Windows 8 requires you to use a Microsoft account.